# HTML - link with text and image on same line?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone I am having a strange problem which I assume has a simple solution but I am at a loss here, I've tried everything I can think of!
I have a link that contains text and an image, and the image should align with the text on the same line. However, the image goes to the next line and I can't find a fix for this!
My code is:

```
<div id="container" style="padding: 5px">
  <a href="page.php">Username<img src="arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

To complicate the issue I have a JS function which changes the background color of the "container" div onmouseover. Therefore I can't use absolute positioning for the *a img* because it moves it outside of the area that changes colors. I have included a screenshot:

[image]

I'm probably overlooking some very small issue so if someone can suggest a fix that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your CSS and a jsFiddle?

Comment: I had to google jsFiddle, but the point stands:  http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/  That is a great little article.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
#container { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Generally, you should post the code that causes the problem. The code posted so far surely doesn’t. My guess is that your CSS has some setting that sets or implies some specific width on the container, causing line wrapping (where an image acts like a character). If this is so, the above code fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way is by adding align="right" to the image, like:

```
<img align="right" src="arrow.png">
```

If that doesn't work. Check if your container gets limited in width by your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.
i created and tested the code here

[http://jsfiddle.net/yaSWM/7/]

edited:
you can removed the `<img>` make it `background` in your style

```
<div id="container" style="padding: 5px">
  <a class="img1" href="page.php">username</a>
</div>
```

add class or id ex. `class="img"`

```
.img1{background:url(arrow.png) no-repeat right center;padding-right:20px;line-height:10px}​
```

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/BEdLJKfP)***

Hi now try this css according to your design

```
#container a{
display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
img{
vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/BEdLJKfP)***

**or**

### ------

Now you can define this image in a class and apply this class in your anchor tag

as like this

```
    .imgclass{
    background:url("your_image_path.png") no-repeat 0 0;  // set to the background-position Acroding to your background Image
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container" style="padding: 5px">
  <a href="page.php" class="imgclass">Username</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

We may use table. Table is one of the way for these type of alignments.

```
<div id="container" style="padding: 5px">
  <a href="page.php"><table><tr><td>Username</td><td><img src="arrow.png"></td></tr></table></a>
</div>
```